# How to disable Block implicitly retains 'self' warning in Xcode 10

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How do you disable this warning in Xcode? I understand the warning message I just want to suppress it.

> Block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate
>   this is intended behavior

Comment: Instead of trying to suppress it, fix the code by doing what the warning states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `-Wno-implicit-retain-self` to the appropriate entry in your build settings. For the full list see [Diagnostic flags in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html)

Comment: Thank you! What is the appropriate entry in build settings?

Comment: @BerryBlue - IIRC something along the lines of "additional compiler flags" (I'm on a tablet - no Xcode)

Comment: Thank you! The field is called "Other Warning Flags".

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to suppress certain code in a class.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wimplicit-retain-self"

.. code ..

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is on purpose. Just disabling it may lead to memory leaks. You could use something like this:

```
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
        __typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        ...
        [strongSelf someMethod];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode select your target and go to `Build Settings`.

The setting that you're looking for is `Implicit retain of 'self' within blocks`.

I copied code from an ancient Xcode project to a modern project and Xcode gave this warning in the new project, but not in the old.
By comparing the Apple Clang Warnings in both projects, I found that this setting was disabled for the old project.
So I enabled it and resolved a bunch of warnings, improving the old app.